# Can you use $(this) inside of $.post()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I can't seem to access $(this) from inside the $.post section. It works fine outside of it. Here's the javascript:

```
    $('.idea').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).html();
        $.post("votes.php", { title: title }, function(data){
            $(this).nextAll('.voteTotal').html(data);
        }, "json");
    });
```

HTML:

```
<h3 class="idea">Idea #1</h3>
<h4 class="voteTotal"></h4>
<p>This is a really cool idea.</p>
<a href="#" class="vote">Click to vote</a>
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11297748/javascript-execution-context-of-function-argument/11297779#11297779

Comment: Well you're not using it inside `$.post` but rather inside an anonymous function that gets called by `$.post` async functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should backup `this` before the callback function:

```
$(".idea").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        title = $this.html();

    $.post("votes.php", { title: title }, function(data) {
        $this.nextAll(".voteTotal").html(data);
    }, "json");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `context` setting, then it'll work:

```
$('.idea').each(function(){
    var title = $(this).html();
    $.post("votes.php", { title: title, context: this }, function(data){
        $(this).nextAll('.voteTotal').html(data);
    }, "json");
});
```